# Laravel 5 Eloquent multiple relationships with multiple wheres

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have 2 tables: `Calendar` and `User`. `Calendar` has a one to many relation to `User` and `User` has a relation with itself via `parentID`:

```
//model Calendar.php
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'userID');
    }
//model User.php
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class,'parentID','id');
    }
```

I already select it like I want but I want to add:

```
where('users.parent.parentID',$userID)->orWhere('users.parent.parentID',$userID);
```

but I don't think it will work. I tried to join, but I don't know how. I've tried:

```
$calendar = calendar::with('users','users.parent')->get()->where('users.parent.parentID',$userID);
```

and

```
$calendar = calendar::with('users','users.parent')->get()->where('users.parentID',$userID);
```

Comment: get() goes last in a model query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar::with('users')
        ->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($userID) {
        $query->where('parentID', $userID)->orWhereHas('parent', function($query) use ($userID) {
            $query->where('parentID', $userID);
        });
    })->get();
```

This will load you all users that have parentID equal $userID OR users which parent have the same condition. For loading relation you have to use `with` function, for filtering relation use callback inside it, for filtering relation owner use functions `whereHas` or `orWhereHas`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$calendar = Calendar::with('users')
                    ->with(['users.parent' => function($q) use ($userID){
                               $q->where('parentID',$userID);
                           }])
                    ->get();
```

More information about relationship eager-loading constraints here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads